# How to undo or reverse np.meshgrid?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

In an image resizing interpolation problem, one could use `np.meshgrid` on row and col indices before operating on the meshed indices:

```
nrows = 600
ncols = 800
image_in = np.random.randint(0, 256, size=(nrows, ncols, 3))
scale_factor = 1.5

r = np.arange(nrows, dtype=float) * scale_factor
c = np.arange(ncols, dtype=float) * scale_factor

rr, cc = np.meshgrid(r, c, indexing='ij')

# Nearest Neighbor Interpolation
# np.floor if scale_factor >= 1. np.ceil otherwise
rr = np.floor(rr).astype(int).clip(0, nrows-1)
cc = np.floor(cc).astype(int).clip(0, ncols-1)

image_out = image_in[rr, cc, :]
```

Now, how would I reverse this process? Say given `rr_1`, `cc_1` (product of `np.meshgrid`) that's processed in an unknown manner (here illustrated by `np.random.randint`), how do I get the `r_1` and `c_1`, that is, the inputs to `np.meshgrid` (preferably with `ij` indexing)?

```
# Suppose rr_1, cc_1 = np.meshgrid(r_1, c_1, indexing='ij')
rr_1 = np.random.randint(0, nrows, size=(nrows, ncols, 3))
cc_1 = np.random.randint(0, ncols, size=(nrows, ncols, 3))

r_1 = ?
c_1 = ?
```

**UPDATE:**

I figured it out immediately after posting. The answer is:

```
# Suppose rr_1, cc_1 = np.meshgrid(r_1, c_1, indexing='ij')
rr_1 = np.random.randint(0, nrows, size=(nrows, ncols, 3))
cc_1 = np.random.randint(0, ncols, size=(nrows, ncols, 3))

r_1 = rr_1[:, 0]
c_1 = cc_1[0]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `numpy.meshgrid` creates a higher dimensional array from input arrays in order to create grid-like arrays. So imagine you want to get a 2D grid by using some input 1D vectors `r` and `c`. `numpy.meshgrid` returns `rr` and `cc` as 2D arrays which respectively hold the y axis or x axis constant  everywhere on the 2D array (this is why it is a grid).

Here is a test case:

```
import numpy as np

r = np.arange(5)      # [0 1 2 3 4]
c = np.arange(5,10,1) # [5 6 7 8 9]

rr, cc = np.meshgrid(r,c,indexing='ij')

r_original = rr[:,0]
c_original = cc[0,:]

print(r_original)     # [0 1 2 3 4]
print(c_original)     # [5 6 7 8 9]
```

Note that the grids we have created for `rr` and `cc` are

```
rr = [[0 0 0 0 0]
      [1 1 1 1 1]
      [2 2 2 2 2]
      [3 3 3 3 3]
      [4 4 4 4 4]]

cc = [[5 6 7 8 9]
      [5 6 7 8 9]
      [5 6 7 8 9]
      [5 6 7 8 9]
      [5 6 7 8 9]]
```

Since you are using `indexing='ij'` in your case and the 2D arrays are transposed. Hence, the values that hold constant for `rr` and `cc` respectively are the x axis and y axis (contrary to the case where you do not use `indexing='ij'`).